# Selenium wait a lot while searching for element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a software to find email addresses in source codes of websites.
But sometimes the sources of the websites are very long, so it searches for a long time.
How can I set a certain time for this and have it switch to the other website url after this time expires?

```
    for query in my_list:
        results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=3, stop=3, pause=2))

    for result in results:
        url = list(result)
        print(*url,sep='\n')
        for site in url:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get(site)
            doc = driver.page_source
            emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', doc)
            for email in emails:
                print(email)
```

results = []
start_time = time.time()
for query in my_list:
results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=3, stop=3, pause=2))

```
for result in results:
    url = list(result)
    print(*url,sep='\n')
    for site in url:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(site)
        doc = driver.page_source
        emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', doc)
        for email in emails:
            print(email)
if time.time() - start_time > 10:
    # if 10 seconds pass do something
    start_time = time.time()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

# your code

while True:
    if time.time() - start_time > 2:
        # if 2 seconds pass do something
        start_time = time.time()
        print("2 seconds passed")
```

Comment: I edited it but it didn't work. I shared the combined version with the code you shared above, can you see?
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want you can add me on discord bilke#1227 and we can talk there

Comment: Sorry I don't use discord, just my codes and any chance to integrate and share your fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait a bit providing time using python  time module as follows:

```
import time

for site in url:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(site)
    time.sleep(8)
```